# LDAP error code 8 for some users but not others

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I have a some problems.

Listed Error:

```
LDAP error code 8
```

Server log:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090202, comment: The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v2580 ]
```

Problem action(?):

- client to login request to server. and server send request to LDAP. Some people can login successfully, but for other some people login failed:

  LDAP response error code 8

Server log got [javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090202, comment: The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v2580 ]]

But I am using LDAP. no LDAPS.

- Some people said check under `KRDOM01 : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ NTDS \ Parameters \ LDAPServerIntegrity = 1`

but my setting is already `LDAPServerIntegrity = 1`

My code:

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+host+":"+port);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
```

Why can some people login ok, but some people got fail?

Comment: Did you test with secure connection ldaps://...?

Comment: no i don't. because almost 2017.04 LDAP was fine. client login error dose not occured. why should i use LDAPS? @Jan

Comment: We would need to know what LDAP server you are using and all relevant configuration information. But why aren't you using LDAPS? That's the easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

These errors indicate your LDAP server is set to Require Signing.

If you connect using SSL, then the data signing is not required.4

If you were able to make an successful bind, then I would "guess" the server you first connected to does NOT have signing enabled and you are being referred to a Domain Controller that has signing enabled.

See:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2545140/fast-esp-unable-to-use-active-directory-accounts-for-authentication-login-fails-with-ldaperr-dsid-0c0901fc

Comment: hmm. @jwilleke thank you. but this is not helpful for me.

Comment: because, i'm able to connect success LDAP auth and sometimes the same connection giving connection refusing errors. if i use LDAP url use cluster.com( this cluster clusting a.com, b.com, c.com ... and so on), sometimes LDAP response LDAP error code 8. but if i use a.clusteredLdap.com, sometimes LDAP response connection refuesed.